# Insert Data with Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables connected with a foreign key constraint. Each table has a primary Key (ProductID ,BaseProductID ) that is an autoincrementing identity column.
Every BaseProduct has only 1 Product during the import.

```
BaseProduct
- BaseProductID
- BaseProductName

Product
- ProductID
- BaseProductID
- ProductName
```

I try to insert rows into both tables from a different Database that has the same Tables, but different seed Values. I dont want to keep the ids from the source database.

Is there a way to do this in one statement?

EDIT

The Select would be

```
Select ProductName FROM @SourceProduct 
WHERE Not ProductName  in (
select ProductName   FROM @TargetBaseProduct
)
```

I tried the solution by Giorgi which is close, but the matching by

```
tgt.BaseProductID = src.BaseProductID
```

leads to  result where source rows with BaseProductID= 1 are not inserted if the target already has an entry with BaseProductID = 1.

```
DECLARE @SourceBaseProduct TABLE
    (
      BaseProductID INT ,
      BaseProductName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
DECLARE @SourceProduct TABLE
    (
      ProductID INT ,
      BaseProductID INT ,
      ProductName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

DECLARE @TargetBaseProduct TABLE
    (
      BaseProductID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      BaseProductName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
DECLARE @TargetProduct TABLE
    (
      ProductID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      BaseProductID INT ,
      ProductName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )


INSERT  INTO @SourceBaseProduct
VALUES  ( 1, 'BaseProduct1' ),
        ( 2, 'BaseProduct2' ),
        ( 4, 'BaseProduct3' )
INSERT  INTO @SourceProduct
VALUES  ( 3, 1, 'Product1' ),
        ( 9, 2, 'Product2' ),
        ( 27, 4, 'Product3' )

INSERT  INTO @TargetBaseProduct
(

      BaseProductName 
      )
VALUES  ( 'Existing Product Base' )

INSERT  INTO @TargetProduct(
 BaseProductID  ,
      ProductName)
VALUES  (  @@IDENTITY, 'Existing Product' )

MERGE INTO @TargetBaseProduct tgt
USING
    ( SELECT    sbp.BaseProductID ,
                sbp.BaseProductName ,
                sp.ProductName
      FROM      @SourceBaseProduct sbp
                JOIN @SourceProduct sp ON sp.BaseProductID = sbp.BaseProductID
    ) AS src
ON tgt.BaseProductID = src.BaseProductID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT VALUES ( src.BaseProductName )
OUTPUT
    Inserted.BaseProductID ,
    src.ProductName
    INTO @TargetProduct(BaseProductID, ProductName);


SELECT  * FROM    @TargetBaseProduct
SELECT  * FROM    @TargetProduct
```

Output

```
BaseProductID   BaseProductName
1               Existing Product Base
2               BaseProduct2
3               BaseProduct3


ProductID   BaseProductID   ProductName
1           1               Existing Product
2           2               Product2
3           3               Product3
```

Expected result

```
BaseProductID   BaseProductName
1               Existing Product Base
2               BaseProduct1
3               BaseProduct2
4               BaseProduct3


ProductID   BaseProductID   ProductName
1           1               Existing Product
2           2               Product1
3           3               Product2
4           4               Product3
```

EDIT

using

```
ON 1 = 0
```

like Giorgi suggested gave the right result

Comment: How does your select look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right, there is way with `MERGE`:

```
DECLARE @SourceBaseProduct TABLE
    (
      BaseProductID INT ,
      BaseProductName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
DECLARE @SourceProduct TABLE
    (
      ProductID INT ,
      BaseProductID INT ,
      ProductName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

DECLARE @TargetBaseProduct TABLE
    (
      BaseProductID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      BaseProductName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
DECLARE @TargetProduct TABLE
    (
      ProductID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      BaseProductID INT ,
      ProductName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )


INSERT  INTO @SourceBaseProduct
VALUES  ( 1, 'BaseProduct1' ),
        ( 2, 'BaseProduct2' ),
        ( 4, 'BaseProduct3' )
INSERT  INTO @SourceProduct
VALUES  ( 3, 1, 'Product1' ),
        ( 9, 2, 'Product2' ),
        ( 27, 4, 'Product3' )



MERGE INTO @TargetBaseProduct tgt
USING
    ( SELECT    sbp.BaseProductID ,
                sbp.BaseProductName ,
                sp.ProductName
      FROM      @SourceBaseProduct sbp
                JOIN @SourceProduct sp ON sp.BaseProductID = sbp.BaseProductID
    ) AS src
ON tgt.BaseProductID = src.BaseProductID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT VALUES ( src.BaseProductName )
OUTPUT
    Inserted.BaseProductID ,
    src.ProductName
    INTO @TargetProduct(BaseProductID, ProductName);


SELECT  * FROM    @TargetBaseProduct
SELECT  * FROM    @TargetProduct
```

Output:

```
BaseProductID   BaseProductName
1               BaseProduct1
2               BaseProduct2
3               BaseProduct3


ProductID   BaseProductID   ProductName
1           1               Product1
2           2               Product2
3           3               Product3
```

EDIT: if you want to insert existing rows too, then change

```
ON tgt.BaseProductID = src.BaseProductID
```

to

```
ON 1 = 0
```

Comment: Nice use of Merge.  One suggestion...  The OP did not want to keep the ID values from the source tables.  So he will want to modify the Merge statement, slightly, to leave the identity columns out, thus accepting those values from the target tables.  EDIT:  I'm assuming that the BaseProductID is also an identity.

Comment: @DeadZone, `sbp.BaseProductID` is placed in source table, because of comparing on it. Increments in targets are working as OP wants. Notice IDs in source tables and in target ones.

Comment: Its close to what I need. I updated the question. If the target already has an existing product with ProductID 1 the Product from Source Product1 is not inserted.

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner, Do you want to insert in any way?

Comment: You mean the direction? I only want to insert into the target tables. The insert in my sample is just to supply some testdata. I try 1=0 now

Comment: Perfect: exactly what I needed. I realy have o look into MERGE. There is more to it than I expected.